# GitHub Action error for Azure Webapp: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file

Tags: .net, github, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I am trying to deploy a small WebApp with GitHub Actions into an Azure WebApp deployment slot. The WebApp in Azure is called `webappdeploydemo` and the deployment slot `development`. The WebApp is based on .NET 6 LTS stack.
For this I use an ubuntu runner and the following YAML-configuration:

```
name: 'Deploy to Azure App Service'

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: webappdeploydemo
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: 6.0.x
      
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release
    
    - name: Publish
      run: dotnet publish -c Release -o '${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}/myapplication'
      
    - name: Deploy
      uses: Azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
        slot-name: 'development'
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
        package: '${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}/myapplication'
```

When triggering the GitHub Action I have an error at the build step, which I am trying to understand and solve. In understood that it can't find a sln or .net project at that path. But why and how can I overcome this?

[image]

Comment: Run `pwd` and `ls` in the `Build` step to verify if it's the correct path where `dotnet build` is supposed to execute.

Comment: The former commands does not understand the project setup without a solution file or a project file that you need to send in. Do you have a solution file at the root of your repository at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to create a `development slot` without any issues. Please follow the below steps.

Make sure your source files are deployed properly to GitHub. Check the folder structure before you continue the steps.

- In Visual Studio, Create a  `.NET Core 6`  Web App.
- Push the code to GitHub Repository.
- New files  `.gitattributes`  and  `.gitignore`  will be created in the GitHub Repo along with the Source Code.

[image]

- Make sure your  `GitRepository`  has all the required solution and folder structure.

[image]

- Create a new App Service.

[image]

- Enable  `Continuous deployment`  for GitHub Actions.

[image]

- Workflow folder will be created in the GitHub Repo.
  [image]

***Output:***
[image]

***Creating Deployment Slots:***

- In  `Azure Portal`  => Navigate to your  `App Service`  => select  `Deployment slots`  Under  `Deployment`  .
- As we have deployed the Application to Azure, we will find one  `Production slot`.

[image]

- Create one  `development`  slot. Provide the name and select the deployed App Service to clone all the deployed configurations and settings to  `development`  slot from  `Production`  slot.
  [image]
- As it is a sample App, it takes few seconds to create the slot.

[image]

- Check the newly created  `development slot`  under  `All Resources`.

[image]

***Initial Output of Development Slot:***

[image]

- Now we need to set the  `continuous deployment`  and integrate the  `GitHub Repo`  code.
- In Visual Studio, create a new branch for  `Development`.

[image]

- Commit and push the changes of new branch.

[image]

- In GitHub, click on  `View all branches`, you will find a new branch.

[image]

- Navigate to the  `Development slot`. Now integrate the GitHub  `development branch`  for the  `development slot`  and click on  `Save`.

[image]

***Final Output for Development Slot:***

[image]